# how to solve circular structure in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, encryption, cookies, cryptojs

i want to use [cryptojs](/questions/tagged/cryptojs) to [encrypt](/questions/tagged/encrypt) [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies), i want to encrypt user id with his network card mac address.
cryptoJS needs to JSON.stringify this data then encrypts.
but i see this error in console:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

this is a snippet of my code:

```
var mac = 'e0:23:e3:46:57:52'
var userInfo = JSON.stringify({_id: user._id, mac: mac})
var cookie = crypto.AES.encrypt(userInfo, 'secret key')
res.cookie('userInfo', cookie, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000000) })
```

Comment: What is the type of `user._id`? I think it might contain a circular reference.

Comment: an Object.id from mongodb

Comment: If the error comes from the `JSON.stringify` call, this has nothing to do with encryption, cookies or cryptojs.

Comment: did this make problem? i test with a simple string but this show error, too

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stringifying of JSON with strings works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`user._id` is `ObjectId`, just convert it to string:

```
var userInfo = JSON.stringify({ _id: user._id.toString(), mac: mac });
```

Also try to use `util.inspect`, it automatically replaces circular links with `[Circular]`.

Comment: mac is a MAC ADDRESS, a string